# Is it possible to run a script which requires elevated permissions from inside zshrc without password prompt

Tags: zsh, sudo, sudoers

I am trying to put a script in my .zshrc that alters the fn key settings on my keyboard. This is done by altering a value inside a read only config file, and I have successfully done it with the command `sudo echo value > /protected/file`. This change is not permanent, and it undoes itself with every reboot, so I decided to stick it in a zsh script that I could append to my .zshrc file. I stuck the command exactly as I previously made it into a zsh script, and I called it in the .zshrc by appending `sudo zsh /path/to/script` to it, and in order to try to allow this script to be ran without entering a password, I modified my sudoers file with visudo, and I appended `msmit ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/script` to the end of the sudoers file. The sudoers file is otherwise default.

When I open my terminal, I always am prompted for my password, because the zshrc is running the script I wrote, but I though adding the script to sudoers was supposed to fix this?

I am running Debian 10, and I am relatively new to linux.